# Cannot draw recycled bitmaps after onStop called from Screen Off

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-imageview, android-lifecycle

in my onStop and onPause methods i do the following:

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (backgroundBitmap != null) {
          backgroundBitmap.recycle();
          backgroundBitmap = null;
        }
}

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
     imageService.setPauseWork(false);
     imageService.setExitTasksEarly(true);
     imageService.flushCache();
}
```

when is switch the screen off onPause and onStop gets called and afterwards i get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps
```

So it seems that he continues drawing but the bitmap is allready recycled ?

My idea is not to recylce my bitmap and let the imageworker continue doing his work, when onStop/onResume is called due to screen off. Is this a good idea or is there a better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got it i use now

```
 pm =(PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 if (pm.isScreenOn() == false) { ... }
```

to check why onResume and onStop are getting called